# ubuntu 12.04 ruby1.8 depends on libreadline5 which does not exist any more?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ruby

I just built a new 12.04 ubuntu box and tried to install puppet package.  This failed because it could not load ruby1.8.  After some fiddling around I tracked the issue down to the fact that the libreadline5 package is no longer available.
libreadline installs version six but libruby1.8 is looking for a package called libreadline5.

For various boring reasons I am stuck with 12.04 and puppet 2.7 (don't ask ;)

Not sure how to proceed from here?

Comment: If you have PE, get support from Puppet Labs. Otherwise get off of 2.7 and onto a modern Puppet version.